# Задача на нахождение кол-ва путей в прямоугольнике. Динамическое программирование

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано прямоугольное поле размером n*m клеток. Можно совершать шаги длиной в одну клетку вправо, или вниз, или по диагонали вниз и вправо(двигаться в других направлениях запрещено). Посчитать, сколькими способами можно попасть из левой верхней клетки в правую нижнюю.
Решал методом динамического программирования, в интернете подобной задачи не нашел, только со стоимостью клеток, что не совсем то. Хочу проверить правильность своего решения. Для следующих размеров мои ответы:

1. 1*3 - 1
2. 4*3 - 19
3. 25*24 - 32247603683099
4. 7*4 - 167

Код следующий:

```
n,m = tuple(map(int, input().split(' ')))
res = [[0 for i in range(n)] for k in range(m)] # Заполнение поля нулями
for i in enumerate(res):
    for k in enumerate(i[1]):
        if (i[0] == 0) and (k[0] == 0): continue # В начальной точке кол-во маршрутов равно 0
        if i[0] == 0:
            res[0][k[0]] = 1 # В первой строке до любой клетки можно дойти только одним маршрутом из начала
        elif k[0] == 0:
            res[i[0]][0] = 1 # В первом столбце также до любой клетки только один маршрут из начала
        else:
            res[i[0]][k[0]] = res[i[0]-1][k[0]] + res[i[0]][k[0]-1] + 1 # Все остальные случаи вычисляются по формуле
            # res[i][k] = res[i-1][k] + res[i][k-1] + 1
print(res[-1][-1])
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101928/discussion-on-question-by-alex--------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта задача решается формулой.

Пусть у нас нет диагонального хода. Сразу разместим все ходы вниз. Теперь нам нужно добавить ходы вправо. А именно, распределить `m-1` раз в одну из `n` ячеек. Это известная формула неупорядоченной выборки с повторениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь надо учесть диагонали. Если у нас есть k диагональных ходов, то их можно сделать  `C(n-1,k)` способами. И, по аналогии, добавим  `m-1-k` ходов вправо (формула есть). Осталось просуммировать. Дальше голая вольфрам альфа. (Опционально, для ускорения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на альфу](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20k%200%20to%20(n-1)%20%7B%20C(n-1%2Ck)%20*%20C(n%2Bm-2-k%2C%20n-1)%20%7D)

Чтобы было понятней распишу сумму на примере 3×4.

```
0: C(2,0)*Cr(3,3) = 1*C(5,2) = 10
1: C(2,1)*Cr(3,2) = 2*C(4,2) = 12
2: C(2,2)*Cr(3,1) = 1*C(3,1) = 3
```

Итого 25 вариантов. Что совпадает с альфой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S сложность можно сделать около линейной от меньшего из размеров, это лучше чем квадрат в лоб и это даже без сворачивания суммы в формулу.

Comment: Добавлю, что количество ходов без диагоналей по полю х*у - соответствующая ячейка в треугольнике Паскаля.

Comment: Логично, учесть что там C(j,i) и находятся)

Comment: мда, а я через один массив(длина наименьшего(столбца или строки)), одну переменную и два цикла(один вложен в другой) эту задачу решил. А тут вона как

Comment: @Miron ну не то чтобы это было необходимо, но почему бы и нет)